# How can I deny access to all files in directory but allow access from specific php file in other directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I have a web app that manages jpg images inside a file /upload. I want to deny access to all images inside /upload from url: domain.com/upload/image.jpg, but grant access to /page.php. I have tried /upload/.htaccess but it denies access to my /page.php file as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does `page.php` "load" the image? By reading the image (using `fopen()` or something) and returning the image data or by simply linking to `/upload/image.jpg`?

Comment: Try redirect match after creating a subfolder images and put all images in it. Put page.php in upload/page.php.

RedirectMatch ^/upload/images/$ http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

> the images are loaded by linking them /upload/image.jpg

If you are linking them from the content generated by `page.php`, then the only way to block it using htaccess is to check the "Referer" (sic) header. This header is sent by the browser to let the server know what URL told it to load that resource. If someone directly goes to an image, the referer could be blank (e.g. if they type it in the URL address bar) or if it's linked from the `page.php`, then the referer will say `/page.php`. However, referers can be easily forged to say anything so this isn't a reliable means to block access.

In the htaccess file in your `/upload/` folder try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Comment: I added this to my .htaccess file:


`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$`RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]`

**Obviously added my page name
**Cleared my Cache

The PHP page works like a charm, but I can still type the URL in the address bar and get the image.

Comment: @BryanJ if you've already loaded the image, it's cached. Have you tried clearing the cache then trying to directly go to the image?